# Data table customization in sProcessing

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I want to change default data table sProcessing as below

```
 dTable = $('#callTable').dataTable({
"oLanguage": {  
sProcessing: "<div id='callTable_processing' class='dataTables_processing'><span>Processing...</span></div>",
    } 
    });
```

I have done above change in one file and it is working ,
but is there any way to put this in common file to apply in all files ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can load your own translations via the `url` option while requesting a JSON.

```
//https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/language_file
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

`' Important : **Text which is displayed when the table is processing a user action (usually a sort command or similar).**

Default:    Processing...

Type:   string

Code example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#example').dataTable( {
       "oLanguage": {
         "sProcessing": "DataTables is currently busy"
       }
     } );
   } );
```